# getting percentage of number then rounding up to nearest .5 cents

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to get percentage off of one cell and then have the answer rounded up or down to the nearest cent amount (.25, .45, .75, .95)

Cell O136= $3.29

=(O136*90%)   =$2.96

Then $2.96 rounded to $2.95

Is this possible

Comment: You post title calls for rounding up, but your example shows rounding down.  Which do you want??

Comment: my bad I would prefer it to round to nearest number weteher up or down if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

`=ROUND(O136*0.9*2,1)/2`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but can I have the number round to the nearest .25 .49 .75 .95

Comment: It rounds to nearest .10

Comment: can you give an example number rounded incorrectly? I'Ve tried with your example 3.29 and it gives the correct 2.95

Comment: probably best if i show you my overall goal

https://www.trophyhut.com/images/Excel%20Question.pdf